# JFROG XRay re-scan of existing artifacts

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-xray

I use JFrog **XRay v1.10.1** with **Artifactory v5.2.1** (both PRO versions).

I cannot found in the XRay documentation (and Google) how XRay automatically re-scan artifacts that have not changed in Artifactory when the vulnerabilities database is updated.

What is the re-scan policy followed by XRay ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xray keeps a graph of all the scanned component and the relationships between them, for example if a certain Java library is part of a war file.
When a new vulnerability is added to the database, Xray will check if the effected component appears in the [dependency graph](https://jfrog.com/article/dependency-tracking/) and if so will check how it impact the rest of the graph. For example if a debian package inside a Docker image is found to be effected Xray will also mark the Docker image as impacted. This is called [impact analysis](https://jfrog.com/article/impact-analysis/) in the Xray terminology.
This is explained in the documentation in the [watches](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/XRAY/Watches) section.

Comment: Thanks you very much :)